# how to change values in matrixXd eigen using block?

Tags: c++, eigen

In my code I am using a MatrixXd array using eigen C++. I want to change my matrix as shown below

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
int main(){
   Eigen::MatrixXd m(3,3);
   m << 1,2,3,
       4,5,6,
       7,8,9;
  // fixed-size block expression
  m.block<1,2>(0,0) = 99; // Compiler Error
  //dynamic-size block expression 
  m.block(0,0,1,2) = 99; // Compiler Error


  std::cout<<m<<endl; 
 }
```

Expected Output:

```
 99  99   3
  4   5   6
  7   8   9
```

Comment: Did you try: `m.block<1,2>(0,0) = 99.` (operator is expecting a double not an int).

Comment: Yes I tried m.block<1,2>(0,0) = 99. gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `m` is a Matrix object you need to write either of these:

```
 m.block<1,2>(0,0).setConstant(99);
 m.block<1,2>(0,0).array() = 99;
```

Alternativly, declare `m` as an `ArrayXXd` object:

```
Eigen::ArrayXXd m(3,3);
m << 1,2,3,
     4,5,6,
     7,8,9;
m.block<1,2>(0,0) = 99;
```

Comment: what if the matrix is declared as dynamic-size block expression

Comment: m.block(0,0,1,2) = 99; // Compiler Error

Comment: Directly assigning a scalar to a block of `m` (or to `m` itself) only works if `m` is an `Array`: https://godbolt.org/z/qB2svR. Otherwise, use one of the alternatives I suggested at the beginning

Comment: Is there any alternate way to change dynamic size block expression which uses eigen matrix?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The alternatives I gave also work for dynamic matrix block expressions: https://godbolt.org/z/Fs-E-J